# How to set input box value in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I've a function that takes a div id and sets the values of few input controls inside it and finally show the div. my function looks like this:

```
function updateDiv(div_id)
{
    $("#"+div_id+" :input[ID^='FIRST']").val('First Name');
    $("#"+div_id+" :input[ID^='LAST']").val('Last Name');
    $("#"+div_id).show();
}
```

but it does not seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post the div content?

Comment: for me it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/8Rvxk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally a bad idea to pass `id`s around as strings. At the very least, you should not select the element three times!

Also, attributes (such as `ID`) should *not* be uppercase.

```
function updateDiv(div_id) {
    var div = $('#'+div_id);
    div.find(':input[id^="FIRST"]').val('First Name');
    div.find(':input[id^="LAST"]').val('Last Name');
    div.show();
}
```

Comment: thank you. one more question please. if i've to update TD table cell instead of an input control, what change would I need to make to the above code?

Comment: @user985812: Can you upload a more complete example to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so that I can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry about the initial confusion. This is what i'm trying to do. Update the td values in the following div:                                                  <div id="mydiv"> <TABLE id="mytable" > <tr > <td id="firstname" >First Name</td> </tr> <tr > <td id="lastname" >Last Name</td> </tr> </table> </div>

Comment: @user985812: If i understood your (second) question correctly, than you want to achieve the same thing you did to the `input` to your table cells now? Simply replace `div.find(':input[id^="FIRST"]').val('First Name');` with `div.find('td[id^="FIRST"]').val('First Name');` (you change `:input` to `td`)

Comment: Thanks Andrej. It worked. In addition to replacing :input with td, I also had to replace val() fn with html().

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a working solution:

The attribute value is case-sensitive, so for example, if `id="firstname"`, the selector would not match.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <input type="text" id="FIRSTNAME"/>
    <input type="text" id="LASTNAME"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var div_id = "mydiv";
    $("#"+div_id+" :input[ID^='FIRST']").val('First Name');
    $("#"+div_id+" :input[ID^='LAST']").val('Last Name');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/JmwcR/3/)